# QGIS 2.14.1 OpenLayers plugin missing

Tags: qgis

I have installed QGIS 2.14.1,  I am looking for the OpenLayers Plugin which I could not find under Install Plugins, as well as Web menu.

Comment: try using quick map services plug in

Comment: Hello  Gerardo,  I am not able to find out Quick map services plug in.

Comment: Does your Plugin Manager actually manage to connect with the online plugin repository?

Comment: Hi, Can you please help me, how can I confirm this? as far as I can see, it starts 'Fetching Repositories'.

Comment: If you are behind a proxy or firewall, it might not get further. Also, check taht you have python-qgis installed too if you are on on a linux system.

Answer (score 3):

After Selecting the Plugin Tab you should be getting
[image]

Connected Status for the url

**QGIS Official Plugin Repository**
http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/plugins.xml
?qgis=2.14

Check the Enabled button is active

as a test check in your browser you can see
http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/plugins.xml with all the plugins available.